# why does this javascript algebraic equation give a result of NaN?

Tags: javascript, function, math, algebra

I have this javascript code, and it is supposed to solve for x and y, but the result it gives is NaN.

```
function calculate(x,y){
                var firsttrans="1";
                var secondtrans="2";
                var a=parseInt(firsttrans, 10);
                var b=parseInt(secondtrans, 10);
                var y=x*a/b;
                var ans=parseInt(y, 10);
                alert(ans);
            }
```

I need `firsttrans` and `secondtrans` to be strings because of something else in my code, but the point is that this `alert(ans)`doesn't give a number.

Comment: What is `x`? Why do you redeclare `y`?

Comment: what inputs are using?

Comment: Why are you defining `var y` if it is a parameter already?

Comment: You have `y` declared twice as function argument and local variable. I've tested your function and it gives the correct result if you pass x as a number.

Comment: **And** note that as `y` is the result of a numeric operation, using `parseInt` on it makes little sense. `parseInt` is for parsing *strings*. If you use it on a number, the number is converted to string, and then parsed as an integer. If you want to truncate the fractional portion, use `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` or `Math.round` (as dictated by your requirements).

Comment: @lilezek Actually `y` is not redeclared, the declaration of _predeclared_ variables is ignored. `y` is re-assigned only.

Comment: @Surreal: The `var` before `y` is definitely wrong (in that it's misleading to anyone coming to the code), but ends up being a no-op. More significantly is that `y` is overwritten before its passed-in value is used for anything.

Comment: What are the values of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Post a *complete* program that demonstrates the problem. Don't make us guess what the value of `x` is. Short answer: if x isn't a number(ish) variable it'll say NaN.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Note that for JavaScript (and/or HTML, and/or CSS) questions, you can include a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem, which makes it easier for people to see the problem and show you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is not guarantee that your x and y are integers or floats, so your operation var y=x*a/b; will fail. You need to make sure that x and y are integers or float.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine (tested in Chrome). I tried `calculate(8,3);` and the answer was **4** not **NaN** so either you're trolling or else you're not telling us an important detail to recreate the NaN issue...

All your code does is simply take `x` value and halves it, then sets that halved result as new value of `y`. Why would a **multiply by own half** give a NaN error? I mean that `y = x * a/b` which does same thing as simply `y = x/2`...

Test this HTML code in your usual browser then against Chrome :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function calculate(x,y){
                var firsttrans="1";
                var secondtrans="2";
                var a=parseInt(firsttrans, 10);
                var b=parseInt(secondtrans, 10);
                var y=x*a/b;
                var ans=parseInt(y, 10);
                //alert("result is : " + ans);

                return ans;
            }

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "result is : " + calculate(8,3);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```